# Add plugin to custom header.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have custom header-ag.php file , wp_head(); is commented because of style reasons, i want to call one plugin, how to add that plugin.
normal header.php is working fine and loading plugin because it have wp_head();.

Advise please.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you call `wp_head` in your custom header file?

Comment: i have stylesheets , which are messing with another language. i have to edit lots of files then, like css classes, so wondering if we directly initizalize a plugin in custom header.

Comment: You should use `wp_head` in your header file otherwise your theme may not work properly because loyts of plugins depend on this hook and without this hook yout theme may lost it's potentials.

Comment: is there a way to initialize plugin in custom header.?

Comment: Have you tried `add_action('wp_head', 'some_function');` ? Can you post your code ?